# upload files to FTP from cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ftp, file-transfer

I am going crazy for finding a way to upload files to a ftp server from inside my app. I already went trough the `easy FTP sample` by apple, trying to port it from IOS to OSX without any success. I also tried the `connectionKit` but after downloading it it doesnt compile. (I have tried every branch of it) I have been going through all the questions posted here and elsewhere about ftp uploading, and most of them are outdated or not understandable. is there somewhere a easy to follow, good, tutorial for FTP file transfer on mac for Xcode? a lot of people would need this, and its absurd that such a important topic lacks so much informations and that every week there is a new topic somewhere about the same question. would it be possible to get an answer here that helps me and future people who need this to find a good, and even more important, up to date information?

i'm on OSX 10.8

thanks to whoever would like to answer this.

best regards

Comment: i'm also interested in this! +1

Comment: Have you looked at `libcurl`? http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: --EDIT-- sorry have read the wrong word! looking!

Comment: call me stupid, but i am not even able to understand what file i have to download! XD i suppose  `Mac OS X i386 7.29.0 binary`

Comment: @Justme I would install Macports (http://macports.org) and install `curl`: `$ sudo port install curl`.  `libcurl` is installed as part of `curl`.  You'll then find libcurl in `/opt/local/{lib,include}`.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks, managed to install it! now i would only need a cocoa tutorial. i am too much of a beginner to understand teh code in another Language and/or environment and translate it to xcode...